# Maven dependency inclusions not working as I expect between modules

Tags: java, maven

This is a really confusing topic for me so I'm asking here for more eyes on the problem. I have a project (work related, so I can not show any real details).

1. The project contains four modules.
2. The first module contains XSD sources, used for class generation.
3. The second module contains the domain, service and rest classes as well as junit tests.
4. The third module contains component tests.
5. The fourth module contain helper classes.
6. The first module has no purpose including the others.
7. The second and third modules includes the first, as those require the generated classes.
8. The third module includes both the second and the fourth, as it requires the domain & service classes and the helper classes respectively. **Note:** By copying the required classes from both the second and the fourth modules, over to the third module, I can make the below command work but that is just so stupid in so many ways.
9. The fourth module includes the second, as it requires the domain classes and the service classes.
10. The main POM file do not include any of the modules as dependencies and the following profile fails, hence me asking this: **mvn clean install -P third**

    ```
    <profile>
      <id>third</id>
      <modules>
        <module>first</module>
        <module>second</module>
        <module>third</module>
        <module>fourth</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
    ```
11. Running the component tests through Intellij, instead of the mvn command above, is successful.

The component was not designed by us and I would like to improve it. Any ideas on how to fix this dependency issue?

Comment: Please make an example project... furthermore using modules in a profile is a very bad idea...

Comment: @khmarbaise I did not make this project, I'm just updating it... How so?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It states that certain domain classes (among others) can not be found... The terminal states: "cannot find symbol", but if I click on the class, that it complains about, in the file in question, then Intellij jumps to the target class in the correct module, so it is not red like if you had missed adding the dependency... I'm so confused...